# How can I export database result in excel file in laravel without clicking on a button?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a SQL result to an Excel file in my Laravel project, but I don't want this operation to be triggered by clicking a button.
It should be downloaded when I enter the correct URL.
If you can provide me with some guidance it will be so much appreciated.
Here's a bunch of code I've been working on:

**UserExport:**

```
use Exportable;
    public function __construct()
    {

     $this->users =User::all();
  
    }

    public function view() : View
    {

     return view('v2.admin.users.export',['users'=>$this->users]);
  
    }
```

**UserController:**

```
public function usersexport(){
       return Excel::download(UserExport::class);
    }
```

**Web.php:**

```
Route::post('/users/export', 'UserController@usersexport')->name('export');
```

Comment: You can use an invokable class for this. That doesn't require a button just the url and no JS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TN0NKHVeWGc

Comment: You should add in your question how you expect the URL to be triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: This response is based entirely on the fact you don't want a button click. Therefore assuming, you will be loading a view, with a excel doc to download on load. As such, I am using the idea of a hidden button which gets clicked via some JS that is not client facing.**

I think the way to do this would be with some vanilla JS, to send a silent request to the userexport function

```
public function usersexport(){
   return Excel::download(UserExport::class);
}
```

1. Make sure the button is not `<button type="submit">` This will reload the page. Instead use `<button type="button">`
2. Add a hidden class to the button `<button type="button" class="hidden">`
3. Add a route attribute to the button. `<button type="button" class="hidden" id="downloadExcelSpreadsheet" data-route="{{ route('export') }}" />`
4. Something like the below should work at the bottom of your page. This is currently using document.ready, which means once the page has finished loading, so all assets and code will be loaded to call the function correctly.

   ```
   <script>
       document.ready = function() { 
           const button = document.getElementById('buttonForExcelDoc')
           button.addEventListener('click', function ( e ) {
           fetch (button.dataset.url)
           .then (response => response.json ())
           .then (data => {
               console.log ('Download should be started/finished')
           })

           button.click();
       }
   </script>
   ```
5. An alternate solution completely negating a button would be this

```
    <script>
            document.ready = function() { 
                fetch ('/users/export/')
                .then (response => response.json ())
                .then (data => {
                    console.log ('Download should be started/finished')
                })
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Added possible alternate solution to negate the need of an invisible button.

Comment: thank you for your response, i will try this solutions. Have a nice day